# looping multidimensional arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So my question is quite simple.
Let me first of all show you my code:

*arrays*

```
$products = array
(     
    array
    (
        'product_id' => 'RD55559955',
        'product_name' => 'Ontsteking (DI) Cassette Zwart Origineel Saab 9-3/9-5',
        'price_excl' => 22600,
        'product_brand' => 'Origineel Saab',
        'product_img' => 'rd123A',
        'brand_logo' => '109943/cache/109943_c45a5b2db2180d48c6e877435f7822ab.png',
        'product_link' => 'www.google.com'
    ),

    array
    (
        'product_id' => 'RD55559955',
        'product_name' => 'een ander product',
        'price_excl' => 22600,
        'product_brand' => 'Origineel Saab',
        'product_img' => 'rd123A',
        'brand_logo' => '109943/cache/109943_c45a5b2db2180d48c6e877435f7822ab.png',
        'product_link' => 'www.google.com'
    )
);
```

*The foreach loop*

```
foreach ($products as $product){

    foreach ($product as $key => $p){

        echo $p['product_name'];
   }
}
```

Gives me error (Warning: Illegal string offset 'product_name' in C:\wamp64\www\mailing\createTemplate.php)

So want i want is to only display the product_name from both arrays.

What am i doing wrong? Appreciate your time!

Comment: Use only 1 `foreach`

Comment: @ascsoftw thanks for commenting. appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 4):

One `foreach` loop is enough:

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    echo $product['product_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following code :

```
for($i=0; $i<count($products); $i++)
{
  echo $products[$i]['product_name'];
 echo "<br>";
}
```